# ¿Cómo hacer una funcion recursiva en Haskell que toma una lista de números y calcula el valor promedio (truncado, usando división entera)?

Tags: haskell

Tengo que hacer la siguiente función recursiva, pero me tira error. ¿Qué está mal?

```hs
promedio :: [Int] -> Int
```

que toma una lista de numeros y calcula el valor promedio (truncado, usando division entera).

#### Mi implementación

```hs
promedio :: [Int] -> Int    
promedio[] = 0
promedio (x:xs) = x / (length xs) + promedio (xs)
```

Me aparece en la consola este error:

```
> Main> promedio1 [2, 3, 3, 5, 7 ,10] *** Exception: divide by zero
```

y tuve que usar div en vez de / porque me aparecían muchos errores.

Comment: Qué error muestra? Edita la pregunta y añade el mensaje de error que te sale.

Comment: Me aparece en la consola este error:                                                                                 *Main> promedio1 [2, 3, 3, 5, 7 ,10]
*** Exception: divide by zero                                                                                 y tuve que usar `div` en ves de / porque me aparecian muchos errores

Comment: de esta manera si funciona bien:                                                         promedio :: [Int] -> Int
promedio[]= 0
promedio (xs) = sum xs `div` length xs                   pero  no entiendo porque haciendo con (x:xs) me tira ese error.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias usar division entera para la suma de un conjunto:

```
promedio xs = sum xs `div` length xs
```

De forma recursiva:

```
promedio :: [Int] -> Int  
promedio[]= 0  
promedio (x:xs) = if (length xs > 0) then (x + promedio(xs)) `div` 2 else x
```

El resultado de la división entera será truncado hacia abajo.

Comment: Tu definición recursiva es incorrecta. Puedes comprobarlo con un simple ejemplo: `promedio [1,2,3,4]` debería ser `2`, no `4`.

Comment: Yo asumia que el codigo estaba mas o menos bien, ya he editado los cambios.

Comment: Asi lo hice y funciona: promedio :: [Int] -> Int
promedio[]= 0
promedio (xs) = sum xs `div` length xs