# Division entera en Haskell

Tags: haskell

¿Como puedo realizar una división entera en Haskell?

Este es mi código:

```
module Summation where 

summation :: Integer -> Integer 
summation n = n * (n + 1) / 2
```

pero me da el error

> No instance for (Fractional Integer) arising from a use of `/'

entiendo que el error se debe a los decimales.

Qué he intentado:

igual probé de esta forma sin éxito

```
module Summation where 

summation :: Integer -> Integer 
summation n = n * div((n + 1) , 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

En la sintaxis de Haskell, los parámetros separados por comas y entre paréntesis, véase (a,b,c,d) son interpretados como tuplas, y la aplicación de funciones se realiza sin paréntesis.

Por lo tanto, en tu segundo ejemplo de código:

```
summation n = n * div((n + 1) , 2)
```

Estás aplicando la operación div a una tupla con dos elementos,n+1 y 2.

Si quieres aplicar div a *n+1* y *2*, se hería de la siguiente forma:

```
div (n+1) 2
```

cómo ves, lo único que se encapsula entre paréntesis es la expresión *n+1* para darle prioridad.

Respecto a tu respuesta, en Haskell las funciones se aplican como un prefijo (Véase, *función* *parámetro* *parámetro2*). Sin embargo, si envuelves el nombre de la función entre *backticks*(`), esta se apricará en forma de infijo( *parámetro1* *función* *parámetro2*). Por eso tu respuesta funciona bien.

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude! Leyendo [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/188924/342) averigué que hay una forma de hacer la división entera y es usar div rodeado de backticks ( si alguien sabe como ponerlo en código le agradezco al edición )

```
module Summation where 

summation :: Integer -> Integer 
summation n = n * (n + 1) `div` 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Mira a ver si esto te sirve de ejemplo, el error esta en usar div (no lleva coma, es solo un espacio)

`summation :: Integer -> Integer`

`summation n = n * ( div  (n + 1) 2 )`

La sintaxis es: div  dividendo divisor

Sin comas entre los dos parámetros